# Twitter's Restriction of Links

Tags: twitter, twitter-api, twitter-search

I have an old Twitter account in which I used to post links to my blog articles, without engaging, as I didn't know the rules. Then I realized that my tweets which contain a link did not appear in search results.

The account remained idle for years. I returned recently, and the problem persists.

Shadow-ban test result is negative. Tweets without a link appear in search results.

I tried their support options, but didn't find an answer.

Is there a known way to have this restriction lifted?